# p-splitbutton remains open after clicked another row

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I have a p-splitbutton inside a tabel with n-rows. When I click and open one it works fine. But when I click on another row it opens the new row clicked but doesn't close the first and the first remains open.

```
 <div *ngIf="action.type !='switch' && action.splitButton && action.type !='expand' && ! 
      (action.hidden && rowData[action.hidden])">
                                <p-splitButton icon="{{action.icon}}" 
                                    (onClick)="action.handler($event, action.type, rowData)"
                                    (onDropdownClick)="actionHandler($event, action.type, 
                                    rowData);action.onMenuClick($event, rowData)"
                                    styleClass="btn {{ action.cls }} mt-1"
                                    [model]="action.items"
                                    pTooltip="{{ getTranslation(action.tooltip) }}">
                                </p-splitButton>
</div>
```

where on onDropdownClick I have two simplie methods that bind the row data selected

[image]

Is there any way to close the rows that not selected?

Comment: It would be easy if you provide stackblitz that reproduce the issue.

Comment: unfortunately I can't

Comment: ok maybe I solved.! In a onDropdownClick method I had the event.stopPropagation(); that blocks the right behaviour. I removed and now it working correctly